# Improving a relatively old self-answered question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer, quality-improvement

Some time ago, I [asked an optimization question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176271/splitting-a-rust-string-into-a-vec-of-its-substrings-with-contiguous-identical-c) that received a few downvotes because I had described my initial solution in the abstract instead of posting actual code.

I then added the code snippet and answered my question with a more optimized, if not completely idiomatic, version, but it's still sitting at a negative score.

What other improvements can I make to the question?

Comment: From the question: "_This works as intended, but is much more verbose than the average rust code that tackles iterative problems like these._". This would make the question off-topic. If the code works, and you simply want to rewrite the code, SO would not be the right place for the question to be.

Comment: I was under the impression that I was missing a precise idiom for this kind of subsequence iteration. This operation is hard to describe succinctly, so I thought the question might be useful to future users who're trying to accomplish it

Comment: is that nit something more fitting to code review. even after the edit, and prior it should be closed of lack of details

Comment: Assuming it's not a duplicate, the original question seems fine to me, although it could be asked more explicitly. Showing a code attempt is probably a net negative overall. However, it's not clear to me how this is an **optimization** question. If you want simple or "elegant" code to accomplish a task, that is a completely separate concern from runtime, memory usage etc.